# How to code it in idiomatic Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I want to write a function `def pair(s:String):Option[(String, String)]` to convert a string into a key-value pair in Scala. The string should look like `"<key>:<value>"`.

How would you correct the solution below ?

```
def pair(s:String) = {
  val a = s.split(":"); if (a.length == 2) Some((a(0).trim, a(1).trim)) else None
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two approaches I personally find a little nicer:

```
def pair(s: String) = s.split(":") match {
  case Array(k, v) => Some(k.trim -> v.trim)
  case _ => None
}
```

Or using Scala's handy regular expression extractors:

```
val Pair = """\s*([^\s:]+)\s*:\s*([^\s:]+)\s*""".r

def pair(s: String) = s match {
  case Pair(k, v) => Some(k -> v)
  case _ => None
}
```

But yeah, yours isn't that bad either.

Comment: I like the 1st approach more :) Could you verbalize _why_ they look to you nicer ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using conditional expressions, but they often have a more imperative or procedural flavor ("check this!", "do that!"), where pattern matching often feels more declarative, and I tend to prefer declarative code.

Comment: I see. You are right. `if` looks like  _Jala_ rather than real Scala.

Comment: @Michael Don't bother with the way things look. There are more important reasons why pattern matching fits better in this particular case. I've explained it in updates to my answer.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: Yes, nice update, but I'll point out that your initial answer was just "looks fine to me". There's a lot of value in the "hell no, there's a nicer way to do this" reactions you're writing off as "worrying about how things look".

Comment: @TravisBrown Concerning the "how things look", it was a reaction on Michael's conclusion of "`if` looks like Java rather than real Scala", which I simply consider wrong. But yeah, I agree, a proper answer takes some analysis to do.

Answer (score 5):

I'd remove the semicolon and make it two lines. Otherwise it's a completely fine functional code.

On the second glance pattern matching seems a bit more appropriate:

```
def pair(s:String) = 
  s.split(":") match {
    case Array(a, b) => Some((a, b))
    case _ => None
  }
```

The reason why pattern matching fits better in this case is that you use `if-else` to emulate a datastructure deconstruction - the exact thing, which pattern matching is for. This drives you to a bit lower level of abstraction, more involved logic and more opportunities to implant bugs. Also as a consequence your implementation relies on partial functions as in `a(0)`, which is always a discouraged practice.

Partial function is a function which is not defined for the whole domain of its input. In your case it means that calling `a(0)` on an empty array will result in an exception, but not in a meaningful functional result. In this particular example you are protected from that scenario by the `if` condition, but in more involved situations if this condition is placed outside of the function body, a use of partial function becomes a potential bug. That's why it is discouraged as a general practice.

But I also must mention that you should not frown upon the `if-else` construct generally. It is a perfectly valid functional expression which has its uses. It's just that in this particular example it was a suboptimal approach.

Comment: To remove ambiguities, `Some(a, b)` should be replaced by explicitly identifying the Tuple2 with `Some((a, b))`.